# Redhat 5 VM Kernel Panic after HV Migration

Tags: virtualization, redhat, hyper-v, migration

I have a Redhat 5.2 VM which was running on VMWare.
I have had to migrate the VM from VMWare to HyperV, so I copied the VMDK files across

I have converted the vmdk files to vhdx files using Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter and that seemed to succeed without issue.
I then created a new Generation 1 Virtual Machine in HyperV, added the 2 VHDX files to it and booted it.

First I was greeted with the RedHat splash screen. So far so good.

[image]

Sadly, it didn't last long. I got a few errors and a kernel panic...

[image]

Having a quick search around, I read that this was likely due to '*The hd controller on the new motherboard is not supported by the drivers in the initrd*' but I cannot seem to get into rescue mode to do anything about this.

Also, that might not even be the issue... has anyone done this before or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: RHEL 5.2 Extented Update Support has ended in March 2010.

Comment: The kernel shown (2.6.18-419) is from 5.11, and would be supportable under Extended Life Support into 2020, if @John has that entitlement add-on from Red Hat.

Comment: Try to reduce chipset version on virtual hardware and use IDE disk instead SATA.

Comment: So the answer is basically here : https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd

Comment: Although i'm having an issue with this, so need to post a new question eitherway. :(